# Отсутствие перевода хинта обсуждаемых на Мете тем

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При отображении хинта в блоке "Обсуждаемое на Мете" виден непереведенный текст:

[image: score]

Перевод в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265311?key=3efbc01bd37781eb2dc07964706b192f) есть, но он не используется.

#### Обновление:

Перевод появился, однако вместо длинного тире нужно использовать знак минуса («−»), т.к. показывается именно разница голосов.